# Pivot scala dataframe with conditional counting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I would like to aggregate this `DataFrame` and count the number of observations with a value less than or equal to the "BUCKET" field for each level. For example:

```
val myDF = Seq(
  ("foo", 0),
  ("foo", 0),
  ("bar", 0),
  ("foo", 1),
  ("foo", 1),
  ("bar", 1),
  ("foo", 2),
  ("bar", 2),
  ("foo", 3),
  ("bar", 3)).toDF("COL1", "BUCKET")

  myDF.show

+----+------+
|COL1|BUCKET|
+----+------+
| foo|     0|
| foo|     0|
| bar|     0|
| foo|     1|
| foo|     1|
| bar|     1|
| foo|     2|
| bar|     2|
| foo|     3|
| bar|     3|
+----+------+
```

I can count the number of observations **matching** each bucket value using this code:

```
 myDF.groupBy("COL1").pivot("BUCKET").count.show
+----+---+---+---+---+
|COL1|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+----+---+---+---+---+
| bar|  1|  1|  1|  1|
| foo|  2|  2|  1|  1|
+----+---+---+---+---+
```

But I want to count the number of rows with a value in the "BUCKET" field which is **less than or equal to** the final header after pivoting, like this:

```
+----+---+---+---+---+
|COL1|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+----+---+---+---+---+
| bar|  1|  2|  3|  4|
| foo|  2|  4|  5|  6|
+----+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a window function, as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.first

myDF.
  select(
    $"COL1",
    $"BUCKET",
    count($"BUCKET").over(partitionBy($"COL1").orderBy($"BUCKET")).as("ROLLING_COUNT")).
  groupBy($"COL1").pivot("BUCKET").agg(first("ROLLING_COUNT")).
show()

+----+---+---+---+---+
|COL1|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+----+---+---+---+---+
| bar|  1|  2|  3|  4|
| foo|  2|  4|  5|  6|
+----+---+---+---+---+
```

What you are specifying here is that you want to perform a count of your observations, partitioned in windows as determined by a key (`COL1` in this case). By specifying an ordering, you are also making the count rolling over the window, thus obtaining the results you want then to be pivoted in your end results.

This is the result of applying the window function:

```
myDF.
  select(
    $"COL1",
    $"BUCKET",
    count($"BUCKET").over(partitionBy($"COL1").orderBy($"BUCKET")).as("ROLLING_COUNT")).
show()

+----+------+-------------+
|COL1|BUCKET|ROLLING_COUNT|
+----+------+-------------+
| bar|     0|            1|
| bar|     1|            2|
| bar|     2|            3|
| bar|     3|            4|
| foo|     0|            2|
| foo|     0|            2|
| foo|     1|            4|
| foo|     1|            4|
| foo|     2|            5|
| foo|     3|            6|
+----+------+-------------+
```

Finally, by grouping by `COL1`, pivoting over `BUCKET` and only getting the first result of the rolling count (anyone would be good as all of them are applied to the whole window), you finally obtain the result you were looking for.

In a way, window functions are very similar to aggregations over groupings, but are more flexible and powerful. This just scratches the surface of window functions and you can dig a little bit deeper by having a look at [this introductory reading](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, explanation, and references!

Comment: I'm glad I've been helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach to get the rolling counts by traversing the pivoted BUCKET value columns using `foldLeft` to aggregate the counts.  Note that a tuple of (DataFrame, Int) is used for `foldLeft` to transform the DataFrame as well as store the count in the previous iteration:

```
val pivotedDF = myDF.groupBy($"COL1").pivot("BUCKET").count

val buckets = pivotedDF.columns.filter(_ != "COL1")

buckets.drop(1).foldLeft((pivotedDF, buckets.head))( (acc, c) =>
    ( acc._1.withColumn(c, col(acc._2) + col(c)), c )
)._1.show

// +----+---+---+---+---+
// |COL1|  0|  1|  2|  3|
// +----+---+---+---+---+
// | bar|  1|  2|  3|  4|
// | foo|  2|  4|  5|  6|
// +----+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I actually really like this 2-stage approach, because decoupling the aggregation from the foldLeft transformation will allow me to wrap this functionality inside a more general function.  Thanks for the response!